# Why do I get the same static ID for the same template Classes?

Tags: c++, templates, static

I watched a Video about someone explaining how an ECS System works in C++.
He included the following Code for getting IDs for different Components.

```
inline std::size_t GetCompTypeID() {

    static std::size_t lastID = 0;
    return lastID++;
}

template<class T>
inline std::size_t GetCompTypeID() {

    static std::size_t typeID = GetCompTypeID();
    return typeID;
}
```

Now when I pass in an int variable then a char and then a int variable again, both integer variables will produce the same ID.

This is the part I don't understand. I know that templates generally only get called into existence on compile time, but I am still calling the function three times and also thus increasing lastID by 1 three times, independend of the actual class I pass.

Why does this work?

Comment: There's a static variable for each template instantiation – which is only initialised once, no matter how many object instances you create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're instantiating the template twice – once for `int` and once for `char` – and the `int` instantiation is called twice.
These instantiations work like any other functions with static variables.

Your use case is equivalent to this:

```
inline std::size_t GetCompTypeID() {

    static std::size_t lastID = 0;
    return lastID++;
}

inline std::size_t GetCompTypeID_int() {

    static std::size_t typeID = GetCompTypeID();
    return typeID;
}

inline std::size_t GetCompTypeID_char() {

    static std::size_t typeID = GetCompTypeID();
    return typeID;
}

int main()
{
    std::size_t int_id1 = GetCompTypeID_int();
    std::size_t char_id = GetCompTypeID_char();
    std::size_t int_id2 = GetCompTypeID_int();
}
```

If you understand why `int_id1 == int_id2`, you understand what is happening.

If you don't, read about static variables in your favourite book.